# How should i display number in HTML for later calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to display number a right and efficient way for later calculation in HTML. This is what i can think of right now but doesn't seems right.

```
<p class = "price"> <span class ="sign">$</span> 10 </p>
```

Later implementation includes

```
$("p.price") * (the desire currency rate being called)
```

It then updates the whole page with the p.price

Comment: Put the number in it's own `<span>` with it's own id and/or class name

Comment: or you can try some data-bind js frameworks like angular, updating DOM is quite convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```html
<p class="price" data-usd-price="10"> any markup you want </p>
```

You can then format it however you like and access the raw value later with:

```js
$("p.price").data("usd-price")
```

Here a bit more complicated example:

```html
<p class="price" data-usd-price="10">foo<span class="converted"></span></p>
<p class="price" data-usd-price="30">bar<span class="converted"></span></p>
<p class="price" data-usd-price="49.99">buzz<span class="converted"></span></p>
<p class="price" data-usd-price="99.99"><span class="converted"></span></p>
```

```js
$('p.price').each(function () {
  $(this)
    .children('span.converted')
    .html(
      $(this).data('usd-price') * 22
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It helps but there is one more thing. How would you run the code when the page load as i am stuck here https://jsfiddle.net/whoq9zd0/ Problem being when the page load the span is left empty but i want it to be shown (GBP as the base)

Comment: @han thereis vanilla JS version of document.ready, but in jquery it will look like `$(document).ready(function(){ $('select').trigger('change'); }`

Also in your code you are using `for`, and you can do it just with selector, and hide rate\prefix\value in data values of options. Try something like this:
`$('select').change( function() {
 console.log($('select option:selected'))
})`

Answer (score 1):

The selector `$("p.price")` will give you an array of all paragraph elements with the class price. So your first issue is that you need to be aware of that, and your current multiplication code is not.

Second, you're trying to multiply the elements rather than the value of the one element.

Third, the value will be a string and you need a number.

I'd try something like:

```
<p class="price"><span>$</span><span class="amount">10</span>
```

Then your JS could look like this (minus smart error checking and optimization and such)

```
var amount = parseFloat($("span.amount:first").text(), 10);

$("span.amount:first").text(amount * exchangeRate);
```

Comment: Ugh, code highlighting not working from mobile... the $10 should be HTML with a span of class "amount" surrounding just the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop through paragraph children and check, if [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) of the children  is text then parse it's [`wholeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/wholeText)

```js
var pContent = $('.price')[0].childNodes,
    elem, num;

$.each(pContent, function (i, e) {
  elem = $(e)[0];
  if (elem && elem.nodeName == "#text") {
    num = parseInt(elem.wholeText);
  }
})

console.log(num)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class = "price"> <span class ="sign">$</span> 10</p>
```

---

> when the page load the span is left empty but i want it to be shown (GBP as the base)

Simply change the spans text on window load instead of `onchange` event

```
var selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
  $('.sign').text(prefix[selectedIndex ]);
  $('.converted').text(currency[selectedIndex ] * $(price).data('price'));
```

Also i have some notes, if you have just one element you don't need to implement `each`  function , and you don't need to make loop on each change as `selectedIndex` will filter the `option` which has `selected` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/whoq9zd0/2/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It helps but there is one more thing. How would you run the code when the page load as i am stuck here jsfiddle.net/whoq9zd0 Problem being when the page load the span is left empty but i want it to be shown (GBP as the base)